# Is it possible to tunnel my whole linux machine through http proxy?

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, tunneling

For some reason i access my internet through a HTTP proxy.

Is there a way to tunnel my whole Linux machine *(currently am using ubuntu 18.04)* through http proxy.

If i change proxy setting in the Ubuntu **Network Settings** the http proxy only works on the browsers. Other apps are left out.

My current workaround is using a Linux VPN CLI which allows connecting through a http_proxy then tunnel the whole machine through VPN traffic *(a service i really dont need)*...this is also a bit costly since i have to pay for the VPN.

I am guessing using stunnel might work since i noted Linux VPN CLI use stunnel??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should go to AskUbuntu.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to tunnel any traffic you need to provide a tunnel entry at the network or IP layer and similar a tunnel endpoint too. A HTTP proxy is only an endpoint at the HTTP layer and can at most be used to tunnel TCP traffic with HTTP CONNECT request. And many HTTP proxies also restrict which ports or protocols such TCP traffic can use (i.e. HTTPS and WebSockets, but not arbitrary TCP).

Therefore you need to have something behind the HTTP proxy which creates a tunnel endpoint at the network level. This is what your commercial VPN provider gives you. But you could build your own tunnel endpoint **if you have your own server of VPS on the internet**. Once you have this you can use your VPN software to reach the tunnel endpoint through a HTTP proxy in a similar way to what your current VPN provider offers.

Comment: I get you... from when i posted the question till now i have been doing research... i noticed **proxychains** works in some apps...there is no vpn involved.
What seems to be the advantage with my VPN is that they use `stunnel` to obfuscate my connection through VPN.

Comment: any other workaround?

Comment: @user190228: proxychains cannot do magic. Even with proxychains there is an external endpoint at the end and you are restricted to what this endpoint allows in terms of network protocols. If it is a HTTP or SOCKS4 proxy for example it cannot do UDP by design. In other words: it all depends on what the endpoint allows you to do and not on the intermediate proxy. The problem is not that it is impossible to create an appropriate setup but that you are not willing to pay in any way for the tunnel endpoint and thus have to use what others might or might not provide for free. Have you tried Tor?

Comment: Okay i didn't know that...
*Its not that am not willing to pay am paying rn....but if i could do it for free that would be great. Also i dont want to change my IP*

Does tor support connecting through proxy's...the last time i tried using tor i couldn't get to tunnel my whole machine through tor

Comment: @xaander1: *"i dont want to change my IP"* - I don't understand that: does your system has a publicly routeable IP address which you want to keep as source IP? Apart from that your connections will have the source IP of the tunnel endpoint, no matter if this is a VPN tunnel, a proxy or whatever. *".the last time i tried using tor i couldn't get to tunnel my whole machine through tor"* - see [How can I make Tor route all my traffic?](https://superuser.com/questions/539203/) for ways and limitations.

Comment: i mean it doesnt matter what  IP i have, no routable IP....also i cant seem to find a way to set internet entry point to **tor** through proxy. I access internet through a http proxy. 
Lets say i manage to tunnel my whole machine through tor lets say using `nipe`... how do i connect tor through proxy since this is how to change tor proxy settings https://aboutdevice.com/how-to-change-the-proxy-settings-of-tor-browser/

Comment: @xaander1: This is no longer an information security problem. It is about routing, i.e. having default route (via Tor) and having a more specific route to the proxy etc. Try superuser.com.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can set up [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for free which will act like a ssh tunnel using web ports

Comment: I believe ngrok is the opposite of what OP wants. Ngrok enables internet access to local ports via tunnel. OP wants internet access via proxy.